# Func<param,param> with lambda

Tags: c#, syntax, lambda

trying to use lambda expressions with predefined "Func" instead of writing it inside the function:

```
var population = ...
if (!(PopulationsList.Any(pop => pop.Name == population.Name && pop != population)))
```

this works. But I don't want lambdas in my code (edit and continue issues)

if population.Name would have been a constant I would have wrote such a predicate:

```
Func<Population, bool> namePred = x => x.Name == constantName;

 if (!(PopulationsList.Any(namePred))
```

How, if at all, can I use such a syntax in my case.
Thanks

Comment: OK - I relise now I can write an extension method to List<population> like that: public static bool containsOther(this List<population pop,string name) but the basic questions persists, and I have a lot of that issue in my code..

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your problem. Your second sample works well: http://ideone.com/cO8jJj What is the problem? I'm not sure but maybe [this](http://ideone.com/4BP7JL) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, the problem with my second example was "constantName" doesn't exist.. But indeed the example you sent me works, and is also refreshing in terms of design, but makes it complicate... (wrapper for each search)

Answer (score 0):

I think the question was not clear enough at the first point.

**Delegates** are just a pointer to a function that the compiler will generate for you.

I see your point of `Constant` here, because you have a `local` variable as a parameter, `Func<Population, bool>` will not only point to a normal `method` it needs also to store the `local` variable population in some way.

**Normal Scenario:**

```
PopulationsList.Any(pop => pop.Name == "constantString")
```

Is Equivelant to:

```
PopulationsList.Any(CompilerGeneratedFunction);

private bool CompilerGeneratedFunction(Population pop)
{
   return pop.Name == "constantString";
}
```

**Complex Scenario:**

(When you have objects included in your lambda, the compiler needs to store this object in some location where the function can access it)

```
input = population;
PopulationsList.Any(CompilerGeneratedFunction);

Population input = null;
private bool CompilerGeneratedFunction(Population pop)
{
   return pop => pop.Name == input .Name && pop != input;
}
```

You can't pass another parameter to `CompilerGeneratedFunction`, since the Delegate signature is `Func<Population, bool>`, so the method should accept a `population` object only and return a `boolean`.

This is not exactly what the compiler does, the compiler might create a class to store the objects in, but it is just a workaround.

Comment: I'm sorry - I think I didn't make my self clear enough.. There's no constant. If there were a constant life would be easy. I wanted to itterate all populations with my func, without using lambda...

Comment: @ephraim And you want to check its `name` against what ? `population.Name` where `population` is a local variable? If so, `Method 1` above is you way to go.

Comment: yap, method 1 works. problem I don't want to use lambdas.

Comment: lambdas are just a syntactic sugar, the compiler generates a normal method for. I think you're missing the real concept of the lambda. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: thanks. The issue is Edit and continue doesn't work with lambdas... 80% of my work (as programmer on a huge project) is with edit and continue, which is disabled for lambdas... that's the whole story...

Comment: @ephraim I hope the answer now makes you more understand why your scenario was a little bit "Complex".

Comment: It is `.Any(CompilerGeneratedFunction)`, without the `()`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You're absolutely correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK - Got it.
Instaed of itterating the predicate function foreach instance of the IEnumerable I can configure in population class the following function:

```
 public class population
{public bool isDuplicateKey(Population pop)
    {
        return pop.Name == this.Name && pop != this;
    }
 }
```

usage:

```
 if (!(PopulationsList.Any(population.isDuplicateKey)))
```

Thanks for all help

Comment: This is an extremely poor way to check.  Instead you should be implementing [IEquatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I'm not checking for equal... I'm checking for existance of same Name. Name is my key, and I don't want to let two DIFFERENT instances with the SAME name. Anyway the point of the question wasn't related to designs, but for syntax,  under the precondition I can't use lambda expressions..